# Fonts with ticks and crosses

Tags: symbols, font-recommendation

Have you come across a font with good ticks and crosses?

The reason I ask is that I'm making a sprite for the uniform.js form plugin (http://uniformjs.com/) and they use Lucida Grande for their checkbox ticks. They look great but I don't have the font and want to increase the size of the checkboxes.

So, are there any fonts (ideally free fonts) that have ticks and crosses included in their character maps?

Comment: Are you on Win/Mac?

Comment: Windows. Sorry, should have said!

Comment: Did you find a tick in unicode?
I have searched but cannot find

Comment: Yeah. Arial Sans Unicode, 'U+2713 Check Mark'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you've looked at the ticks and crosses available in Arial Unicode MS, Wingdings and Wingdings 2. Can be difficult to find in Character Map though, as they don't appear at consistent points in the Unicode table.

These are not free fonts of course, but given you're producing an image sprite rather than embedding, this is not an issue.

Comment: Yeah I've looked at the Wingdings ones, I'm not overkeen to be honest. Didn't think of Arial Unicode though, that looks pretty good to me, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I use Wingdings 2: Capital O for a cross; capital P for a tick.